# How to check if a gerund relationship is exist and valid in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, many-to-many

I have a scenario in which I have a table that is combination of many-to-many relationship, I want to make sure that relationship of association exists only once , no repeating records do exists in it.

I am pasting data over here, I need to make sure that there is not repeating , that violates "gerund" property.

```
ItemID  ProductID   ProductAssociationGroupID   
3064    10084   11  
3065    10705   11  
3066    11766   68  
3067    11766   75  
3068    11772   106 
3069    11778   11  
3070    11779   98  
3071    11779   93  
3072    11793   93  
3073    12073   20  
3074    12178   12  
3075    12561   12  
3076    12561   17  
3077    12561   82  
3078    12561   81  
3079    12561   77  
3080    12561   76  
3081    12573   37
```

How may I query to find out the exact relationship exists only once in the above data?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "Gerund". A quick google only finds explanations about grammar. Are you just asking how to ensure `ItemID,ProductID` is unique?

Comment: Gerund ~ Many-to-Many relationship

Comment: Are you wanting to compare ProductID with ProductAssociationGroupID?

Comment: There is a table , which has Many-to-Many relationship, ProductID, ProductAssociationGroupID , I want to make it sure that this association does not exists not more then once, for this I need to write a query, kindly help. how may I find a query that the unique records does not exists more then one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am still awaiting some clarification on the columns, but I believe using the HAVING clause will give you the results you want.

```
Select ProductID, ProductAssociationGroupID
from [Database]
Group by ProductAssociationGroupID, ProductID
Having (Count(ProductAssociationGroupID) = 1)
```

If you want to find duplicates, then I would just change the HAVING clause to greater than.

Answer (score 2):

The approach I generally use is to use SQL to GROUP BY the columns that you want to ensure are unique, and then specify that the query should only return results HAVING a COUNT(*) > 1 to find any where there are multiple values.

E.g.

```
SELECT
    ProductID
    , ProductAssociationGroupID
    , COUNT(*) AS CountRows
FROM
    YourTable
GROUP BY 
    ProductID
    , ProductAssociationGroupID
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

This should only return rows where there are duplicates.

Comment: Just saw this posted a couple minutes before mine.

Comment: That's it, I did this.